# Java: Storing a selected value for later use

Tags: java

What I need help with is this, I am learning Jave by creating the below simple sales calculator. I have a section within this code as follows:

```
System.out.println ("Please make a selection:");
System.out.println ("1. Octopus Tentacles, 2. Rat Droppings");
System.out.println ("3. Sharks teeth, 4. Mountain Oysters");
System.out.println (" ");
// Since we don't have a primary database to pull from we use a dummy DB
while ( foodCount <= 1 )
{
System.out.print( "Enter selection (1 , 2, 3, 4): ");
result = input.nextInt();

if ( result == 1)
    System.out.println( "You selected Octopus tentacles, price $4.99" );
else if ( result == 2)
    System.out.println( "You selected Rat droppings, price $3.49" );
else if ( result == 3)
    System.out.println( "You selected Sharks teeth, price $6.73" );
else if ( result == 4)
    System.out.println( "You selected Mountain Oysters, price $9.95" );
break;
}

System.out.println (" ");
```

it allows a selection to me made, what I want to do is have that value stored for use in the Price input section alittle below that. Can someone help me please? I am new to Java and learning my way through my own walks of reading books searching the internet but havent found anything that will help me in this instance. Any assistance with this would be appreciated.

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

class priceCalc {

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int Quantity;
  int result = 0;
  int foodCount = 1;
  double Price, Subtotal, SalesTax, TotalSale;
  NumberFormat curForm = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
// Here is a simple display of available products
  System.out.println (" ");
  System.out.println ("Welcome to the IP2 part 2!");
  System.out.println (" ");

  System.out.println ("Please make a selection:");
  System.out.println ("1. Octopus Tentacles, 2. Rat Droppings");
  System.out.println ("3. Sharks teeth, 4. Mountain Oysters");
  System.out.println (" ");
// Since we don't have a primary database to pull from we use a dummy DB
  while ( foodCount <= 1 )
  {
  System.out.print( "Enter selection (1 , 2, 3, 4): ");
  result = input.nextInt();

  if ( result == 1)
    System.out.println( "You selected Octopus tentacles, price $4.99" );
  else if ( result == 2)
    System.out.println( "You selected Rat droppings, price $3.49" );
  else if ( result == 3)
    System.out.println( "You selected Sharks teeth, price $6.73" );
  else if ( result == 4)
    System.out.println( "You selected Mountain Oysters, price $9.95" );
  break;
  }

  System.out.println (" ");
    // Create Scanner for input
  Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Quantity
  System.out.print ("Please enter quantity: ");
  Quantity = key.nextInt();
  System.out.println (" ");

    //Price    
  System.out.print ("Please input price (price amount w/no $): ");
  Price = key.nextDouble();
  System.out.println (" ");

    //Subtotal
  Subtotal = Price * Quantity;
  System.out.println ("Your subtotal is: " +curForm.format(Subtotal));

    //Sales Tax
  SalesTax = Subtotal * .065;
  System.out.println ("Your sales tax is: " +curForm.format(SalesTax));

    //Total Sale
  TotalSale = Subtotal+SalesTax;
  System.out.println ("Your total sale price is: " +curForm.format(TotalSale));
  System.out.println (" ");
}
}
```

Comment: I still don't get where's the problem

Comment: Theres not a problem with the code the way it works, it works fine. The problem is I want to have the price automated so when I make the selection above 1, 2, 3, 4, the price will be stored and called to be the input for the price below after the amoount for quantity is added.

Answer (score 1):

I have made relevant modifications and also given reasons for them.

```
class priceCalc {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        /*
        You don't need a BufferedReader and also a Scanner, any one will do.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        */

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        /* 
        Changed variable names to camelCase
        http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java
        */
        int quantity;
        int result = 0;
        double price[] = new double[4];
        double subTotal, salesTax, totalSale;
        NumberFormat curForm = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        // Here is a simple display of available products
        System.out.println (" ");
        System.out.println ("Welcome to the IP2 part 2!");
        System.out.println (" ");
        System.out.println("Enter prices for each product");
        System.out.println("Octopus tentacles: ");
        price[0] = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Rat Droppings: ");
        price[1] = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Sharks teeth: ");
        price[2] = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Mountain Oysters: ");
        price[3] = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Please make a selection:");
        System.out.println ("1. Octopus Tentacles, 2. Rat Droppings");
        System.out.println ("3. Sharks teeth, 4. Mountain Oysters");
        System.out.println (" ");
        // Changed while into an infinite loop that will break on any input other than 1, 2, 3, and 4.
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print( "Enter selection (1 , 2, 3, 4): ");
            result = input.nextInt();
            if ( result == 1) 
            {
                System.out.println( "You selected Octopus tentacles, "+price[0]);
                subTotal = price[0]*getQuantity();
            }
            else if ( result == 2)
            {
                System.out.println( "You selected Rat droppings, "+price[1] );
                subTotal = price[1]*getQuantity();
            }
            else if ( result == 3)
            {
                System.out.println( "You selected Sharks teeth, "+price[2] );
                subTotal = price[2]*getQuantity();
            }
            else if ( result == 4)
            {
                System.out.println( "You selected Mountain Oysters, "+price[3] );
                subTotal = price[3]*getQuantity();
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println ("Your subTotal is: " +curForm.format(subTotal));
            salesTax = subTotal * .065;
            System.out.println ("Your sales tax is: " +curForm.format(salesTax));
            totalSale = subTotal+salesTax;
            System.out.println ("Your total sale price is: " +curForm.format(totalSale));
            System.out.println (" ");
        }

        System.out.println (" ");
        /*
        You don't need a second Scanner within the same scope
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        */
    }
    public static int getQuantity()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter quantity: ");
        int q = input.nextInt();
        return q;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Powercat - you would be well advised to always use curly braces around all of your conditionals, even one-liners, as John provided here in his answer.

Comment: I understand this coding here, however, how do I declare the "Price" for it to work?

Comment: Okay I got it declared and its set no errors, until I run it. I have removed the input (commented) but not sure how I set the parameters so the declared value goes in the space needed:    System.out.print ("Please input price (price amount w/no $): ");
          //Price = key.nextDouble();
    System.out.println (" ");

Comment: @Powercat - why do you need to obtain price from user, when you already have prices listed? Also you could use price as an int array to store prices of 4 products.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped what I wanted. I didnt need to obtain it as you guys already helped me to declare it as a stored value like I needed, what i needed to do was change the line to read price per each item that was previously declared and have that value printed as well as be placed into the calculation. But I figured out what was wrong and it works the way I needed it to work. The int array was one of the choices I was trying to do but coldnt figure out how to do it. So if you'd like to post that info here that would be great. In the interim, Thank you for your help!

Comment: Alternately, i wish I could vote for you, but I just started and don't have enough reputation haha, sorry my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd expect a beginner mistake to be an improper scoping of `result` - where you would store something into it, but not be able to access it from a parent scope.  However, `result` is scoped appropriately here.

Your example looks incomplete, as you're attempting to loop (on `foodCount <= 1`) - but you're always breaking, so you never actually loop.  As such, you should only have one selection - and the value of `result` is available in your later code for use in your calculations - right next to `Price`, `Subtotal`, `SalesTax`, and `TotalSale`.  (Following Java conventions, these variable names should all begin with a lower-case letter.)  However, I am confused why you are prompting for an input price, after the user already selected an item with an associated price - unless this is what you're trying to correct.

+1 for John's suggestion / answer.  Following this, you can remove your prompt for price.  However, you'll need to first declare `price` above along with your other variables for this to work.

Comment: Yes I am trying to correct this. again I am new to Java and I am learning, since I will be working with SQL I want to slowly get more skills with java so I can eventually learn how to connect the two.